# Angular AuthGuard blocks access and redirects but the page is then stuck on loading

Tags: angular

The Routes look like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NewsfeedComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id/edit',
        component: NewsfeedEditComponent,
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: NewsfeedNewComponent,
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: NewsfeedViewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: NewsfeedHomeComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

When I now open the browser at a protected route the AuthGuard correctly denies access and redirects to `localhost:4200/`. But at that url the angular applications never gets loaded and I only see the loading screen that usually takes like one second. I then need to refresh the page for it to display the starting page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with help of this comment on a github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16211#issuecomment-296526518

I simply added a redirect in the `canActivate` method of the guard before it would return false.

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, I think you need to redirect again to a particular URL from the default base path. (localhost:4200). you can youse something like
{ path: '/', redirectTo: 'mainpageURL', pathMatch: 'full' },

Comment: But shouldn't it display the `NewsfeedHomeComponent`? Because it changed the url correctly but I have to manually refresh the browser for the application to load.

Comment: Yes, it should. but try to redirect it again. also, you can use this.router.navigate to achive redirection. give a try.